# Debian installer mentioned that unused LVM VG and LV will be "formatted"

Tags: debian-installer

I just made a preliminary attempt to do a new installation with the
stretch installer.

I currently have six disks in my machine. Only two are supposed to
play any role in this installation. Let's call them `sda`, `sdb`,
`sdc`, `sdd`, `sde`, and `sdf`. `sde` and `sdf` are brand new and unused disks.

`sda` and `sdb` are both mirrors of a sw RAID device, `md1`, and
similarly `sdc` and `sdd` are mirrors of a sw RAID device, `md0`.

`md1` has the LVM VG `debian` on top of it. `md0` has the LVM VG `data` on top of it. My main system is on the LVM group `debian`. The `data` VG is for auxiliary stuff. In any case, `sdc` and `sdd` are smaller and older drives.

In the present case, I was trying to do an install on `sde` and `sdf`. In
a similar fashion to the above, I was trying to first create a sw RAID
device on `sde` and `sdf`, with a view to then creating a VG on top of
that new sw RAID device.

However, during the partitioning step, after I try to mark `sde` and `sdf` to be used for RAID and try to save, I see this message:

```
The following partitions are going to be formatted LVM VG debian, LV
swap as swap
```

The LV `swap` is part of the VG `debian`.

This message makes me unhappy. I'm not sure what it means, and I don't
see why the VG `debian` needs to be mentioned during this step. And if
the installer is activating VGs for some reason, why is the other VG
`data` not mentioned here as being activated? And if "formatted" just
means that the VG is going to be activated, that's unfortunate
terminology.

I don't want anything else mentioned other than the two disks I'm
working on.

I can add the tree produced by `lsblk` if anyone thinks it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I realised the answer to this after posting the question, and then verified it on another installation attempt, which was also a failure, but got a bit further.

The Debian installer automatically enables RAID partitions it sees. In my case, the only RAID partition on my machine is a Logical Volume on the `debian` Volume Group. So the installer had to enable the Debian VG in order to access the swap partition for use with the installation.

Whether the installer should automatically enable swap it sees is another matter, of course.